# How to import webpack generated output file into an App that has already installed modules that are already in the output file?

Tags: javascript, webpack, highcharts

I have 2 apps that have Highcharts already installed

and I developed a separate react component that uses the Highcharts lib.

So I used webpack to generate that component with its dependencies to be imported into the 2 apps.

I did that to make the code DRY so I don't have to write the component code into 2 Apps.

How to import the generated output file from webpack into these apps without giving me the error of reinitializing Highcharts?

In other words how to import the file without any conflicts with the already installed libs in the Apps?

### Update

I want the lib to be in the bundled file when in case of importing it into an application that doesn't have the lib.

### Update II

I want the lib to be in the bundled file when the client application doesn't have the lib, and when the application has the lib the bundled library is the one that is used by the component.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that environment of your code already have some library you can exclude this library from bundle using *externals*: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Lets say we make a react components library and we need to install `react`, but we know that we will use our components in our react application where `react` is already installed.

So, we can mark `react` as `externals` in our webpack config like:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  externals: {
    react: 'React'
  }
  // ...
};
```

Also we can use `DllPlugin` for exclude any library or any code from our bundle. https://webpack.js.org/plugins/dll-plugin/

You should add external library to `peerDependencies` for your own library and add external library to `dependencies` for your application, then you should exclude external library from bundle of your own library using `externals` or `DllPlugin` and you will achieve your goal.

**UPD:**

If you want to include or exclude external library from your bundle depending on your application you should compile your library two times: with external library and without external library and import needed variant in your application.

Also you can use *dynamic imports* in your library: check exists the external library in current environment and if doesn't - import it.

**But these two cases are not ok**, we don't do so.

**Webpack can't resolve dynamic imports** and the external library **anyway will still be bundled**.

NPM team created `peerDependencies` specifically for **occasions like yours.** **This is the industry standard.**

Read these, please:

1. https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#peerdependencies
2. https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/#externalize-lodash
3. https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/

*I don't know how to convince you...*

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I have tried that already but that is not helpful in my case. I updated the question. Can you please check it?

Comment: @AhmedEl-Masry can you clarify your question?

Comment: I want the lib to be in the bundled file when the client application doesn't have the lib, and when the application has the lib the bundled library is the one that is used by the component.

Comment: I don't think that this way is really good. Look at other libraries, you should include the lib to `peerDependencies` and exclude it from bundle of your own library. It's standard for libraries, `peerDependencies` just exists for this case